# If date and time is not in TIMESTAMPDIFF format then how to find the interval with mysql?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

A jQuery script is used to pick date and time. The format is "Sunday 31 January 2016 - 00:55". I want to run mysql to find date-time interval. But it is not in TIMESTAMPDIFF format. So how to find the interval?

I used this script for picking date & time
http://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Pretty-Date-Time-Picker-Plugin-For-Bootstrap-Material.html

Comment: If this has got something to do with stored dates in MySQL, then store those dates using a date data type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was:

```
 $d = "Sunday 31 January 2016 - 00:55";
 $date = date("Y-m-d H:i",strtotime($d));
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add the format to the options object of your datetime picker to get the date in the required format:

```
$('#yourElement').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker({
    format : 'YYYY-MM-DD'
});
```